# Do other users of One for All live inside Midoriya somehow or are they just memories?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Midoriya is frequently seeing or feeling former users of One for All since season 1 of the anime when he was able to break Hitoshi mind control. Now in season 5 the first owner is telling Midoriya he can't show him more of his past because he only can handle 20% of One for All. What are these feelings/ images supposedly?

Do other users of One for All live inside Midoriya somehow or are they just memories?

Comment: Until we get a more complex explanation from All Might or someone, we can only speculate, but my personal opinion is that they are representation of the experience and consciousness of the other users that has accumulated in One for All. I think at the meeting between the past users, someone explains how that is happening.

Comment: @RigaCrypto does All Might knows the reason? If so, why haven't he explained anything to Deku yet? From the episodes we saw, Deku did had a discussion with All Might, but he didn't had any explanation. He also told that the vision which Deku is seeing is very much different to what All Might saw in the past.

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami Maybe not All Might, maybe Deku will get a better explanation further into the story after immersing himself into his subconcious meetings with the past users and thus discovering new how OFA works. As i said, at this point there is only speculation.

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like is that "One For All" is showing Midoriya the memories of each previous owner or clues that might help him. I believe that they are just memories not actually other people living inside him because if you look back at it all Might had a similar vision to him, but not to the same extent as Midoriya and the original owner never talked to all might he only talked to Midoriya.

Answer (score 1):

If you think back to the sports festival Midoriya sees all the people who at 1 point had the quirk one for all including All Might himself but All Might was not only still around he was watching the festival so my theory is that all former users are with Midoriya in spirit

Answer (score 1):

To be honest they have they're memories shared inside One for All where from the first user till the one who used it last will be seen in those memories of the current user.

1. That power itself spreads to generation to generation which makes it powerful and help the user experience the power where they share the same goal.
2. The power can be used to it's full potential once the user has enough emotional attachment to it.
3. The power if at some point falls under the hands of All for One it will become a catastrophe and he might even have tears based on the emotions of all previous users combined.
4. As soon as All Might dies he might even have his memories passed to midoriya.

Comment: In Deku's meeting with the past users and regarding their conversations, I say it is not only the memories that are preserved in OFA. Deku casually discusses with past users and they give him advice and personal opinions, not only memories and glimpses into their past selves.